# Spamassassin AWL: From: address is in the auto white-list

Tags: email, spam, spamassassin

I am not sure what does this flag means in Spamassassin score checking?
My test returned "1 of 5" and mentioned this:

```
1.0 AWL AWL: From: address is in the auto white-list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the beautiful Wiki [entry](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.3.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_AWL.html#item_n) it is:

> This plugin module provides support for the auto-whitelist. It keeps
>   track of the average SpamAssassin score for senders. Senders are
>   tracked using a combination of their From: address and their IP
>   address. It then uses that average score to reduce the variability in
>   scoring from message to message and modifies the final score by
>   pushing the result towards the historical average. This improves the
>   accuracy of filtering for most email.

So the sender of your mail in combination with the IP was responsible for a high volume of Spam on your system.

Comment: It turned out that it just remembered the sender from previous messages, and the previous issue was: not enough html text for the amount of images (one). So not actually spam.